# Is it possible to push current version of master in github to my site?

Tags: git, heroku, terminal, command-line-interface, devops

Before anything else, I would just like to say I'm new to this DevOps thing (Not even sure whether we can count this as DevOps) but, out of sheer curiosity, is it possible for me to push the current version of my master branch in github onto my site much like how you can just type this on terminal to update the heroku app to the latest version of master in github?

```
git push heroku master
```

Would appreciate your answers. I'm really curious whether it's possible since I think it'll be way faster and easier for me to type a command onto terminal than to open my FTP and upload the files onto the site manually. Thanks!

Comment: David, make attempts then report your result if you got stack over flow .

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [GitHub pages](https://help.github.com/categories/github-pages-basics/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide from Heroku that explains more in detail how to integrate GitHub, you can find it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration.

Apart from the guide that should help you to achieve what you want. you could also take a look at git remotes https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes.

Currently probably you have only one:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/foo/bar (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/foo/bar (push)
```

To add a new remote you could do something like:

```
git remote add <shortname> <url>
```

Something like:

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/foo.git
```

To push to your new remote you could do:

```
git push heroku master
```

Probably if your remote is empty you could force your local revision to the remote repo:

```
git push -f heroku master
```

These are some of the basic steps, but better check the links to get a better idea.

[git remote / git fetch / git pull / git push](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing)